# jQuery count div, divided into two and add between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tell me how to make a jQuery:
count `<div class="one">`, divided into two and add between them `<div class="two">`

`/div class="one"/` can be a different number

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8b8tnm3/)

Comment: what is your actual requirement... do you want to add a separator like `<div class="two"></div>` between `x` number of element with class `one`

Comment: yes, i need '<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class selector to find all the `one` elements, then use its count(`length` property) to find its middle and insert the new element

```
var $ones = $('.one');
$ones.eq(Math.floor(($ones.length-1)/2)).after('<div class="two"></div>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qo6rh23k/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a div after the half of the `one` divs:

```
var count = Math.floor($('.one').length / 2);
$('.one').eq(count).after('<div class="two">d</div>');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c8b8tnm3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you.

```
   var ones=$('.one');
   var indexofOne=$('.one').length/2;
   indexofOne=Math.floor(indexofOne);
   var insertPosition=$('.one')[indexofOne];
   $(insertPosition).after($('<div class="two">'));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8b8tnm3/3/)